Can not download anything via Python Requests module
Code:
import requests

url = "``https://github.com/something/something/releases/download/1.0/something.exe``"`

destination = r"C:\Users\something\Downloads"

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:

    with open(destination, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)  

else:

    print(f"Failed HTTP Status Code: {response.status_code}")

Output: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: C:\\Users\\something\\Downloads
I have already tried running it as admin but still nothing. Also I have tried to change folder permissions but everything was just right?

destination = r"C:\Users\something\Downloads" Presumably that is a directory.  You cannot write to a directory as though it were a plain file.  You need to put a filename , i.e. something like destination = r"C:\Users\something\Downloads\myfile.txt"

Your destination needs to be a filename, not an existing folder. And, you need to specify a raw string as shown below:
for example:
url = "https://github.com/CharlesKnell/folder-display/blob/main/dist/folder_display_2.2.1.exe"
destination = r"C:\Users\charl\Downloads\folder_display_2.2.1.exe"

